# SQL DATEDIFF of am pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, datediff

i want to calculate the time difference between two times, but my problem is maybe the second time will be after midnight, and the first before it like:

```
time 1  = '2015-08-02 09:30 PM'   
time 2  = '2015-08-03 02:30 AM'
```

so in this case the difference between them will be negative,
i try to multiply the value returned by **-1** to convert it to positive value, but other data will be wrong..

my code is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-08-02';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2015-08-02';
DECLARE @EmpID nvarchar(6) = '12345';

SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN(DATEDIFF(minute, a.[Time], @StartDate)) < 0
then DATEDIFF(minute, a.[Time], @StartDate) * -1 
ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, a.[Time], @StartDate) END
)

FROM
Attendance a
WHERE
(EmpID = @EmpID OR @EmpID IS NULL)
AND a.[date] <= @EndDate
GROUP BY EmpID
```

so how can i solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't the `END` be after the `ELSE` in your `CASE` statement? Is that a typo or is your code like this?

Comment: yes Raj, i have corrected it..

Comment: Maybe try to convert data to 24 format with `Convert(datetime, '2015-08-02 09:30 PM')` for example.

Comment: @PatrykImosa that will not make a difference, datediff will automatically attempt to cast the second and third parameter as datetime. For all we know, the columns may already be datetimes anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in your code. But i would use this syntax instead:

```
SUM(ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, a.[Time], @StartDate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following:

```
CASE WHEN a.[Time] > @StartDate 
THEN DATEDIFF(minute,@StartDate,a.[Time])
ELSE DATEDIFF(minute,a.[Time],@StartDate)
END
```

Should do it and will always give a positive value.

```
select datediff(minute, '2015-08-02 09:30 PM'  ,'2015-08-03 02:30 AM')
```

Returns 300, which is correct (5 hours, 5 * 60 =300)